# Error in rowSums(out_pathway) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r

i am trying to solve this problem an you help me:

```
kegg_brite_map <- read.table("E:\\Path\\KoG1\\picrust1_KO_BRITE_map.tsv", header=TRUE, sep="\t", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, comment.char="", row.names=1)
```

test_ko <- read.table("E:\Path\KoG1\test_ko.tsv", header=TRUE, sep="\t", row.names=1)

##Run function

```
### Reproducing the categorize by function (level 3) functionality in plain-text tables.
### Doing this because adding a column of KEGG Pathways to a table and then converting
### that table to BIOM is difficult.

categorize_by_function_l3 <- function(in_ko, kegg_brite_mapping) {
  # Function to create identical output as categorize_by_function.py script,
  # but with R objects instead of BIOM objects in Python.
  # Input KO table is assumed to have rownames as KOs and sample names as columns.

  out_pathway <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=0, ncol=(ncol(in_ko) + 1)))

  colnames(out_pathway) <- c("pathway", colnames(in_ko))

  for(ko in rownames(in_ko)) {
    
    # Skip KO if not in KEGG BRITE mapping df
    # (this occurs with newer KOs that weren't present in PICRUSt1).
    if(! ko %in% rownames(kegg_brite_mapping)) {
      next
    }
    
    pathway_list <- strsplit(kegg_brite_mapping[ko, "metadata_KEGG_Pathways"], "\\|")[[1]]
    
    for(pathway in pathway_list) {
      
      pathway <- strsplit(pathway, ";")[[1]][3]
      
      new_row <- data.frame(matrix(c(NA, as.numeric(in_ko[ko,])), nrow=1, ncol=ncol(out_pathway)))
      colnames(new_row) <- colnames(out_pathway)
      new_row$pathway <- pathway
      out_pathway <- rbind(out_pathway, new_row)
    }
    
  }
  
  out_pathway = data.frame(aggregate(. ~ pathway, data = out_pathway, FUN=sum))
  
  rownames(out_pathway) <- out_pathway$pathway
  
  out_pathway <- out_pathway[, -which(colnames(out_pathway) == "pathway")]
  
  if(length(which(rowSums(out_pathway) == 0)) > 0) {
    out_pathway <- out_pathway[-which(rowSums(out_pathway) == 0), ]
  }
  
  return(out_pathway)
  
}
```

#Run function to categorize all KOs by level 3 in BRITE hierarchy

```
test_ko_L3 <- categorize_by_function_l3(test_ko, kegg_brite_map)
```

#ERROR

Error in rowSums(out_pathway) :
'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
Called from: rowSums(out_pathway)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! The example in your question is not minimal and (without data) not reproducible. Please give a [mre] in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Without this question being reproducible (see comment from @jogo), it is difficult to tell where you have issues in the code, but the error is telling you that your argument 'x' to the function `rowSums()` must be at least two dimensions. This makes sense because you need rows, to be able to take the sums of each of them.

`out_pathway` is the object that you are passing to `rowSums()`, so this is the place to start. This object must not have two dimensions, possibly because you are doing some aggregating, and then deleting columns in the lines above.

If `out_pathway` is just a one-dimensional object, you can just use `sum()`